Why are sculpt tools doing this weird square thing?
When using my drawing tablet and the sculpt tools if I press lightly or move too quickly these squares randomly start generating at the max radius and strength of the brush! It's incredibly difficult to sculpt with it randomly doing this, any thoughts?
Recorded example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SXy2VYsk9VYODu1vlwdVRrKQO7zQV_Cu/view?usp=sharing
It did this for a while, stopped yesterday which was blissful and now it's doing it again!
All drivers are up to date, I tried adding Blender as a specific application in Wacom Center and nothing changed.
Version: 4.1
Tablet: Wacom Cintiq 13HD

Have you applied the scale to your mesh? Ctrl+A > Scale.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

I don't remember where I saw the post, but the solution that worked for me was to first make sure in your Wacom tablet settings to disable "Use Windows Ink".
Then in Blender's settings under Input category, change the Tablet API to "Wintab".
Hope that helps you like it did me.



So far, working like a dream! Thank you so much!
